# How to convert assembly code from solc into EVM bytecode

Tags: assembly, solidity, bytecode, evm

I want to find a appropriate method to compile assembly code, generated from my Solidity code using "solc --asm," into EVM bytecode. I thought the the flag --assemble for solc is a correct approach for converting either the assembly code or the opcodes from my Solidity code into bytecode. Regrettably, I didn't find much document on the --assemble mode.

Any guidance on this or proper documentation would be very helpful. Thanks.